# Função deletar da lista

Tags: java, lista

Tenho essa função para deletar da lista encadeada pelo valor:

```
public void deletar(Object valor) {
        Node temp = head;

        while(temp != null) {
            if(temp.getNext().getValor().equals(valor))  {
                temp.setNext(temp.getNext().getNext());
                break;
            } else { 
                temp = temp.getNext();
            }
        }
    }
```

Mas o último elemento sempre causa `NullPointerException`, não deleta, como soluciono isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você está tentando chamar temp.getNext().getNext(), mas a primeira chamada do getNext() pode retornar null, e isto não está sendo checado.

Primeiro devemos checar se a cabeça é não nula

```
        if(head == null)
            return;
```

Em seguida, checamos se devemos atualizar o nó raíz.

```
        if(head.getValor().equals(valor)){
            head = head.getNext();
            return;
        }
```

Por fim buscamos o valor desejado, atualizando a ligação anterior `temp`:

```
        temp = head;
        prox = temp.getNext();
        while(prox != null) {
            if(prox.getValor().equals(valor))  {
                temp.setNext(prox.getNext());
                break;
            } else { 
                temp = prox;
                prox = temp.getNext();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

O Código completo é o seguinte:

```
public void deletar(Object valor) {
        Node temp, prox;

        if(head == null)
            return;

        if(head.getValor().equals(valor)){
            head = head.getNext();
            return;
        }

        temp = head;
        prox = temp.getNext();

        while(prox != null) {
            if(prox.getValor().equals(valor))  {
                temp.setNext(prox.getNext());
                break;
            } else { 
                temp = prox;
                prox = temp.getNext();
            }
        }
    }
}
```